# Reading only emails with attachments

Tags: python, dataframe, email, outlook, attachment

I am writing a script that should only be taking in Outlook emails that are unread and have attachments, and then putting the contents into a data frame.

The code below seems to be returning an empty data frame though, not sure if it's possible to read only emails with attachments?

This is my code so far:

```
contents = []

for mail in message:
    if mail.UnRead == True and mail.Attachments == True:
        contents.append(mail.body)
        contents.append(mail.Subject)
        mail.UnRead == False

#and finally converting a list into dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(contents)
```

Comment: What is `message`?  Show us exactly how that variable is created.

Answer (score 0):

`MailItem.Attachments` is a property that returns the `Attachments` collection object, not a boolean value. Your check must be `mail.Attachments.Count > 0`.

That being said, never loop through all items in a folder - it is like running a SELECT query in SQL without a WHERE clause. Let Outlook (the store provider) do the heavy lifting - use `Items.Find/FindNext` or `Items.Restrict` with a query like

```
@SQL= ("urn:schemas:httpmail:read"=0) AND ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1B000B"=true)
```